# PyTorch - Shapes Don't Match

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Unfortunately, I get the following RuntimeError:

[image]

This error hapens at epoch 1 during the last batch (so all other batches run through),
and I don't know what causes the error in my code. Here is a code snippet of my function

```
def gradient_penalty(critic, real, fake, device):

    BATCH_SIZE, C, H, W = real.shape
    epsilon = torch.rand(size = (BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 1)).repeat(1, C, H, W).to(device)

    # generate tensor filles only with ones
    x = torch.ones(size = (BATCH_SIZE, C, H, W), dtype = int)

    # interpolate images
    interpolated_images = real * epsilon + fake * (x - epsilon)
```

The variable `real` stands for images and has the shape `(128, 3, 64, 64)`.
I need to admit that I don't find the error message concretely, i. e. where don't the shapes of the tensors coincide?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your last batch has most likely only *123* elements, **not** *128* as expected.

Comment: Can you show me the part of the code where you have `if batch_size == 123`?

Comment: I honestly already forgot what I exactly I did because I now use this approach: `noise = torch.randn((real_images.shape[0], z_dim, 1, 1)).to(device)`. And then I let the generator take the noise as input: `fake = gen(noise)`. Previously, it was `noise = torch.randn((batch_size = 128, z_dim, 1, 1)).to(device)`, so looking at my code from the question, for the last batch, fake would have the shape `(128, 3, 64, 64)`, and so naturally, I would get the RuntimError. Thanks for your hints again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can discard incomplete batches when instantiating a [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) with the `drop_last` argument:

```
torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=128, discard_last=True)
```

However, this seems a bit drastic measure since *128* elements from your dataset will go to waste.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks a lot for the hint! In this case, I'm training on the CelebA dataset with more than 200k images, so discarding a few images in the order of 100 won't do anything, I guess..